# Nexus OSS v3.12.1-01 groovy script fails with Nested DB TX

Tags: exception, groovy, nexus

I face a problem while executing an admin script, written in groovy. The original goal is removing all zip files from all repositories. My approach was iterating through all repositories, finding components containing the "zip" extension in a single transaction, while removing them in the next transaction.

I wrote the following script to achieve this approach

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.Repository
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Component
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageTx

// get repos
final Iterable<Repository> repositories = repository.repositoryManager.browse()

// iterate
repositories.each {
    Repository repo ->
        if ("hosted".equals(repo.type.toString()) &&
                "maven2".equals(repo.format.toString())) {
            log.info("Found hosted repository " + repo.name)
            managePossibleZips(repo)
        }
}

/**
 * Manage zip files for given repository
 * @param repo
 * @return
 */
def managePossibleZips(Repository repo) {
    // get storage facet
    final StorageFacet storageFacet = repo.facet(StorageFacet)
    // find zip files
    final Iterable<Component> components = findZips(storageFacet, repo)
    // erase zip files
    if (0 == components.size) {
        log.info("No zip files in this repository")
    } else {
        eraseZips(storageFacet, components)
    }
}

/**
 * Find components, that contain extension 'zip', based on supplied repository and storageFacet
 *
 * @param storageFacet the storage facet
 * @param repo the supplied repository
 * @return Iterable < Component >  List of components containing zip files
 */
def findZips(StorageFacet storageFacet, Repository repo) {
    // get transaction
    final StorageTx transaction = storageFacet.txSupplier().get()
    // tx
    transaction.begin()
    // find components containing zip files
    Iterable<Component> components = transaction.findComponents(
            Query.builder().where('extension =').param('zip').build(), [repo]
    )
    // commit
    transaction.commit()
    // close
    transaction.close()
    // return components
    return components
}

/**
 * Erase supplied components
 *
 * @param storageFacet the storage facet
 * @param components list of components to be erased
 */
def eraseZips(StorageFacet storageFacet, Iterable<Component> components) {
    components.each { Component component ->
        // get transaction
        final StorageTx transaction = storageFacet.txSupplier().get()
        // tx
        transaction.begin()
        // find components containing zip files
        transaction.deleteComponent(component);
        // commit
        transaction.commit()
        // close
        transaction.close()
        // return components
    }
}

log.info("All done, bye bye")
```

While trying to execute the script the following error pops up in the syslog

```
2018-10-09 10:53:07,809+0200 INFO  [qtp402299672-4809]  admin org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'nx32' [script] runNow
2018-10-09 10:53:07,809+0200 INFO  [qtp402299672-4809]  admin org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'nx32' [script] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
2018-10-09 10:53:07,821+0200 INFO  [quartz-5-thread-18]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.script.ScriptTask - Task log: /opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/log/tasks/script-20181009105307817.log
2018-10-09 10:53:08,174+0200 INFO  [quartz-5-thread-18]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.script.ScriptTask - Found hosted repository ps-myrepo-mvn
2018-10-09 10:53:08,175+0200 WARN  [quartz-5-thread-18]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskJob - Task d446ea78-eeb0-4b17-be55-3e611e696762 : 'nx32' [script] execution failure
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Nested DB TX!
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.script.ScriptServiceImpl.eval(ScriptServiceImpl.java:153)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.script.ScriptServiceImpl.eval(ScriptServiceImpl.java:162)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.script.ScriptTask.execute(ScriptTask.java:78)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.scheduling.TaskSupport.call(TaskSupport.java:93)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskJob.doExecute(QuartzTaskJob.java:145)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskJob.execute(QuartzTaskJob.java:108)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.thread.internal.MDCAwareRunnable.run(MDCAwareRunnable.java:40)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectRunnable.doRun(SubjectRunnable.java:120)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectRunnable.run(SubjectRunnable.java:108)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Nested DB TX!
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:155)
        ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Nested DB TX!
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:135)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageTxImpl.<init>(StorageTxImpl.java:154)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacetImpl.openStorageTx(StorageFacetImpl.java:263)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacetImpl.lambda$0(StorageFacetImpl.java:145)
        at com.google.common.base.Supplier$get.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
        at Script25.findZips(Script25.groovy:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:151)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl$2.invokeMethod(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:301)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
        at Script25.managePossibleZips(Script25.groovy:29)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
        at Script25$_run_closure1.doCall(Script25.groovy:16)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2040)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2025)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2066)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$162.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at Script25.run(Script25.groovy:11)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to wrap your transaction in a try-catch block and always close your transaction, like this:

```
try {
    tx.begin()
    components = tx.countComponents(Query.builder().where('1').eq(1).build(), [repo])
    tx.commit()
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.warn("Transaction failed {}", e.toString())
    tx.rollback()
} finally {
    tx.close()
}
```

Also you probably need to restart Nexus, to get rid of the locked transactions. Otherwise each script with a transaction will yield now the Nested DB TX exception

Edit: the countComponents() function in my code is just an example

Comment: Unluckily we worked around this program with a rather radical approach: talking about moving to a different artifact host. So, unluckily, I can't test this anymore.